# Change working directory for docker build in Azure DevOps

Tags: docker, azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps Build Image Docker Task (1.*), I have docker file in sub directory as shown
[image]

The docker build command is running in the 'deploy' folder and fails so I want it to run in the parent folder 'caduceus' or basically want to simulate this command

```
docker build -f caduceus/deploy/Dockerfile ./..
```

which runs fine in my local machine. Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

You should put `./..` in `buildContext` not in `arguments`

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I do not see anything called build context in my docker task version 0.*, 1.* or 2.*, also I do not see Any command buildandpush

Comment: It is strange because I use the same and have this option to set.

Comment: @RadiumBall could you double check this?

Comment: Yes I have edited and added the complete screen grab no 'Build Context' :(